# Regular expression to match requiring a module?

Tags: regex

I'm using regular expressions in a custom text editor to in effect whitelist certain modules (assert and crypto). I'm close to what I need but not quite there. Here it is:

```
/require\s*\(\s*'(?!(\bassert\b|\bcrypto\b)).*'\s*\)/
```

I want the regular expression to match any line with `require('foo');` where foo is anything except for 'assert' or 'crypto'. The case I'm failing is `require('assert ');` which is not being matched with my regex however `require(' assert');` is correctly being matched.

https://regexr.com/4i6ot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to match `assert` or `crypto` between `'`, you could change the lookahead to assert exactly that. You can omit the word boundaries matching the words right after the `'`.

If what follows should match until the first occurrence of `'`, you could use a negated character class `[^'\r\n]*` to match any char except ' or a newline.

```
require\s*\(\s*'(?!(assert|crypto)')[^'\r\n]*'\s*\)
                                  ^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BBlgxt/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use: `require\s*\(\s*'(?!(\bassert'|\bcrypto')).*'\s*\)`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80MkS/1)

The difference is that I replaced word boundary `\b` with `'` at the end of the module names. With `\b` a module name of `'assert '` was matched by negative lookahead, because `t` was matched by `\b`. In the new version, we require `'` at the end of the name of the module.

**EDIT**

As Cary Swoveland advised, leading `\b` are not required:

```
require\s*\(\s*'(?!(assert'|crypto')).*'\s*\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80MkS/2)

Comment: I don't see why you need the word boundaries. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried to change the OP version as little as possible. I've added another regex without `\b`s

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need anything remotely that complicated, this simple pattern will work just fine:

```
require\((?!'crypto'|'assert')'.*'\);
```

**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZkFhdJ/2)**

Comment: It doesn't match `' assert'` nor `'assert '` and if I understand correctly, it should.

Comment: @mrzasa Oh right, I misunderstood the requirement, this should work perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the flawed regex that if there is a match the string between `"('"` and `"')"` is to be captured. One way to do that follows.

```
r = /
    require             # match word
    \ *                 # match zero or more spaces (note escaped space)
    \(                  # match a left paren
    (?!                 # begin a negative lookahead
      '                 # match a single quote
      (?:assert|crypto) # match either word
      '                 # match a single quote
      (?=\))            # match a right paren in a forward lookahead
    )                   # end negative lookahead
    '                   # match a single quote
    (.*?)               # match any number of characters lazily in a capture group 1  
    '                   # match a single quote
    \)                  # match a right paren
    /x                  # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

As the capture group is followed by a single quote, matching characters in the capture group *lazily* ensures that a single quote is not matched in the capture group. I could have instead written `([^']*)`. In conventional form this regex is written as follows:

```
r = /require *\((?!'(?:assert|crypto)'(?=\)))'(.*?)'\)/
```

Note that in free-spacing regex definition mode spaces will be removed unless they are escaped, put in a character class (`[ ]`), replaced with `\p{Space}` and so on.

```
"require ('victory')"  =~ r #=> 0
$1 #=> "victory"
"require (' assert')"  =~ r #=> 0
$1 #=> " assert"
"require ('assert ')"  =~ r #=> 0
$1 #=> "assert "
"require ('crypto')"   =~ r #=> nil
"require ('assert')"   =~ r #=> nil
"require\n('victory')" =~ r #=> nil
```

Notice that had I replace the space character in the regex with `"\s"` in the last example I would have obtained:

```
"require\n('victory')" =~ r #=> 0 
$1 #=> "victory"
```